# CSS - Style only the 3rd and 5th h2 element

Tags: css

In the following HTML markup, I'm trying to style only the 3rd and 5th h2. But whatever I try it doesn't work.

```
    <div class="row services">
            
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <div class="service-card">
                    <h2>First h2 title</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
                
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <div class="service-card">
                    <h2>Second h2 title</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
                
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <div class="service-card">
                    <h2>Third h2 title</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
                
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <div class="service-card">
                    <h2>Fourth h2 title</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
                
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <div class="service-card">
                    <h2>Fifth h2 title</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
                
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <div class="service-card">
                    <h2>Sixth h2 title</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```css
.services div:nth-child(3) .service-card h2,
.services div:nth-child(5) .service-card h2 {
  color: #f60;
}
```

```html
<div class="row services">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
    <div class="service-card">
      <h2>First h2 title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
    <div class="service-card">
      <h2>Second h2 title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
    <div class="service-card">
      <h2>Third h2 title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
    <div class="service-card">
      <h2>Fourth h2 title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
    <div class="service-card">
      <h2>Fifth h2 title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
    <div class="service-card">
      <h2>Sixth h2 title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```